# Why my crontab can not work with /etc/crontab file

Tags: cron

In my project, I want to make a  scheduled task with cron.

So I added a line into  /etc/crontab

```
*/10 * * * * root /home/JobidUserJobname/JobidUserJobname.sh
```

and the content of  /etc/crontab is like:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed
*/10 * * * * root /home/JobidUserJobname/JobidUserJobname.sh
*/1 * * * * root date
```

and I restart the crontab service:

```
#service crond restart
#service crond reload
```

and they executed successfully.

But when I executed:

```
#crontab -l
```

It shows:

```
no crontab for root
```

It seems nothing wrong. My linux OS is:

```
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
```

Who can help me?

Comment: This is probably a better question for [unix.se]. It's not really a programming question (unless you consider `crontab` to be a simple programming language).

Comment: This might also be a duplicate of this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/127732/10454 -- you need to understand the distinction between system crontabs and user (including `root`) crontabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crontab -l gives the output "no crontab for root". This is expected since it will show only crontabs added using the command crontab -e. The crons added in "/etc/crontab" will not be listed in crontab -l command.

Things to check. 
1. Check if the file "/home/JobidUserJobname/JobidUserJobname.sh" has execute permission. If no then execute the below command.

```
chmod +x /home/JobidUserJobname/JobidUserJobname.sh
```

2. If its still not working append a "/bin/sh" before the script.

   */10 * * * * root /bin/sh /home/JobidUserJobname/JobidUserJobname.sh
3. Check the cron logs to see if there are any errors.